Errors like TS2353 do not cause build to fail: How to make sure the linter or compiler throws an error?
For the following line:
const { data: items } = useFindItems({ owner: user.id });

I am getting this correct error in IntelliJ:
TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and owner does not exist in type FindItemsQuery

The field owner simply dos not exist on that options object. However, I am not able to configure  ESLint or TypeScript in such a way that this simply does not compile or, at the very least, throws a linter error.
This mistake above did end up in actual builds already for some time, only for me to discover later that the error was correctly displayed by IntelliJ once I opened the file, but not during running eslint or expo build.
What do I need to do in order to make this fail my builds (or linting process)? I've been trying to play around with several ESLint rules and tsconfig.json settings but without any success.
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "types": [
      "react-native",
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "paths": {
      "@firebase/auth": [
        "./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/index.rn.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}

expo/tsconfig.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}


You can add the typescript-eslint plugin, or use npm run tsc to fail on typescript errors reference.

@eten thank you, I'll try this when I can. I feel like this should not compile at all but somehow expo build does let this through. I must assume that expo would also to some compilation at some point where this should simply fail..

If your actual build doesn't do all the checks you want, why not e.g. "prebuild": "tsc --noEmit"?

I can't reproduce it. Can you provide your tsconfig.json? Does it contain noEmitOnError? Does it contain suppressExcessPropertyErrors? The question is unclear. The title is "How to make sure the linter or compiler throws an error?" Do you get an error message in the build step? Do you want the error in the linting step or build step. Both is possible. You don't need a linter to break the build step.

@jabaa I added the tsconfig. I noticed that tsc is indeed throwing the error as expected. However, I was not able to silence errors from the node_modules/ directory. It is still odd to me that running expo build does not verify this by its own.

Two down-votes and one close-vote. This community has become a tough place.

What is this "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"? I have to ask for each configuration file and you mention two down-votes and one close-vote.

@jabaa sure thing,  I added the file to my question. It comes with the expo package.

It looks like expo doesn't use the TypeScript compiler to build the project. "noEmit": true means that no build artifacts are created. "You can then use TypeScript as a tool for providing editor integration, and as a source code type-checker." https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noEmit. You can do, what jonrehsparpe suggested, even without --noEmit, because it's already configured in both tsconfig.json.

@jabaa I guess I'll then just run tsc with the linter in order to make sure I don't bring errors into production .. Created a follow-up question since I can't get rid of errors inside node_modules/.

tsc is the TypeScript compiler, not the linter. ESLint is a linter.

@jabaa I am aware of that. I just didn't understand why this would not fail during biuld. Having the linter do the job is just the plan B).

If you're aware of that, you know that "I'll then just run tsc with the linter" makes no sense. Either you run tsc or the linter.

@jabaa when I wrote that, I meant npm run lint && npm run compile (or so). So I run tsc and the linter ;)

I still don't understand why you need a linter. I can't reproduce the problem. When I run tsc I get the errors. Running tsc should be enough.

I assumed that expo somehow ignores these errors but, as it turns out, tsc is likely not even called by expo. I thought the linter might also be able to catch this error. Another reason is that I still cannot use tsc, because I can't manage to get rid of the errors coming from node_modules/.
